# Deleting empty rows

Tags: excel, vba

On left if what data I have and on the right is how I need the data to look.

[image]

If you think a non-VBA solution would be better, let me know.

Comment: There's no question here...

Comment: With the possible exception of mashing potatoes, VBA is the best way to do **anything**.

Comment: Are you looking to simply stack the values without spaces in between? If so, insert a column between them and add the formula =Row() into columns b and d, Then copy/paste values over the formulas. Then you can sort column A:B by column A to get column a grouped together. Then a second sort on B:A to reorder them back to the original sort order. Repeat for columns C:D.

Comment: I will help you as in your previous question but can you indicate in your question what is happening when 'b' is not present in column B and update F colum and perhaps also your image to reflect this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RemoveBlankCells()

'Deletes single cells that are blank located inside a designated range
Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

This will select a range and find any blank cells in that range and delete it. Just amend the range as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your problem is to sort your different cells .
You can make a function Where You select an input range ( column A and B in your screenshot) and with VBA you make a function who detect empty cells and sort the range .
For detect empty cells you can use IsEmpty ( "your cell" ) .

Answer (score 0):

I usually do so:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Change number for column selection
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

In your screenshot, cells start from row 1 but after deleting blank cells you have first row blank. If You also need this you can use:

```
Cells(1, 1).Insert 'Change second number for column selection
```

Answer (score 0):

In E2 use this *array* formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$999, MATCH(0, IF(LEN(A$1:A$999), COUNTIF(E$1:E1, A$1:A$999), 1), 0)), "")
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in *braces* (e.g. **{** and **}**); you do not put these in yourself.

Once entered correctly, fill right one column to catch the values in column B and then fill E2:F2 down as far as necessary to catch all of the unique non-blank values from columns A and B.